# How to keep triangles connected and the same shape, while modifying/transforming?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, constraints, instances

EDIT:
All green triangles should keep the same shape as the purple triangle. They may not deform in any other way than location and rotation. If I work with modifiers the triangles keep deforming. 
I also don't want to move all triangles manually. The triangles/blender need(s) to know that the triangles form one structure, connected on the corners.

All help is appreciated. 
If necessary I'm willing to learn Sverchok or Houdini or any other way to solve this...

[image: All green triangles should keep the same shape as the purple triangle]

old:
I want to do the following:

- I model the shape like a i would normally do, the triangles will 'replace' it.
- All of the structure is made of one base triangle, without the triangle being deformed.
- (Only) the corners of the triangles are connected (snap to vertex)
- I can change the scale of the base triangle for more or less detail
- In the end I will replace the triangle for a more complicated object

All help is welcome
[image: 'triangle plane']

[image: hand transformed example of a more organic shape]

[image: Also more complicated]

Answer (score 2):

There are matrices inside sverchok.
Category Analiser - origins node to find matrices.
use category Viz - viewer bmesh to show triangle and matrices to make multiple items.
Or use category Scene-mesh instancer node

Also surface way of this task exists
Please, import this node tree https://gist.github.com/78da59d7bcba7ee9b90e9276a09022d5
in "sverchok import panel"
copy link and press "import from gist"

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to build a mesh out of triangles and keep the triangles connected together as one, try this method.

**1)** Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> to join them all as one object (if not done already).

**2)** Go into edit mode and assign a vertex group for all of the vertices by pressing <kbd>A</kbd>, then in the vertex tab, creating a new vertex group. While in edit mode, press 'Assign' in the vertex group tab to assign those vertices to the group.

**3)** In the modifiers tab, select 'Weld', and select the vertex group you used for the triangle. Set the distance value to something around 0.015m, and the duplicate vertex value to 0.

**4)** Apply the modifier.

Now all the triangle vertices should be connected (where they are touching each other), and they form a single mesh.

If you are still having trouble with this/this didn't fully answer the question, please say so in the comments below.

Comment: I managed to weld the corners together. Now I still need to be able to move the triangles without changing the scale or dimension. None of the triangles edge lengths should change. They are allowed to rotate and move in space. 
Maybe it would be easier to be able to generate/convert a mesh to equal and connected triangles. A bit like the decimate/subdivide modifiers. Let me know if i'm not clear.

Comment: You can individually fill the holes in between the triangles after welding, to create a tri- lowpoly mesh if that's what you are asking.

Comment: I edited my original post to explain my problem more clearly.

Comment: You may be able to add hooks to the triangles that have scaling drivers controlled by the main mesh. This would cause the triangles to increase or decrease in size, but I'm not sure if that would work.